# How to create for-loops with jq in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, variable-expansion

I'm trying to split a json file into various json files. The input (r1.json) looks like :

```
 {

    "results" : [

                {
            content 1
}
,
{
            content 2
}
,
{
            content n
}

    ]
}
```

I'd like the output to be n files : 1.json, 2.json, n.json. Respectively containing {content 1}, {content 2} and {content n}.

I tried :

```
for i in {0..24}; do cat r1.json | jq '.results[$i]' >> $i.json; done
```

But I have the following error: error: i is not defined

Comment: Give [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) a go! In this case, it says "Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.

Comment: Great link, thx a lot. It allowed me to amend my command  `code`for i in {0..24}; do jq <"r1.json" ".results[$i]" > .json; done`code`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the above answers are correct, note that interpolating shell variables in jq scripts is a terrible idea for all but the most trivial of scripts. On any of the solutions provided, replace the following:

```
jq ".results[$i]"
```

With the following:

```
jq --arg i "$i" '.results[$i | tonumber]'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tip @Santiago Lapresta. indeed the simple line that I mentioned above worked well without using jq --arg, but for something more elaborated, issues arise. How would you use jq --arg for nested loops. For example my script is supposed to do something like [that](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83ouwgo62eoyov1/SOF.sh?dl=0)

Comment: I don't really understand what that script does. Can you provide a simpler example? You shouldn't need loops outside jq most of the time; just use `range` inside the jq process instead.

Regarding `--arg`, you can do more than one `--arg` invocation if you need several variables to be passed inside.

Also, considering the script you link; you should probably use `-r` on jq instead of stripping quotes with `sed`.

Comment: finally I found the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509937/how-can-i-do-jq-nested-for-loops-from-bash) to the nested loop issue. Would you know some good documentation to understand how jq works ?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
for i in {0..24}; do cat r1.json | jq ".results[$i]" >> $i.json; done
```

Note that shell variables can't be expanded inside of single-quotes.

IHTH

Answer (score 3):

The single quotes are probably what is messing you up. Bash variables are not expanded in single quotes. You are passing a literal string `.results[$i]` to `jq`. Try double quotes instead:

```
for i in {0..24}; do
    cat r1.json | jq ".results[$i]" >> $i.json
done
```