# How can I do jq nested for-loops from bash?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, nested, jq

I have 52 json files (r$i.json) containing each 25 results (0 to 24). I'd like to create a json file with a special name for each of these results. The name would be composed according to the content of each of these results : YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_company_jobtitle.json

the command generating names work fine :

```
#!bin/bash
for ((j=0;j<=24;j++))
do
   datein=$(jq <"r1.json" ".results[$j].date" | sed 's/"//g')
   dateout=$(date -d "${datein}" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
   company=$(jq <"r1.json" ".results[$j].company" | sed 's/,//g;s/"//g;s/ //g')
   job=$(jq <"r1.json" ".results[$j].jobtitle" | sed 's/,//g;s/"//g;s/ //g')
   jq <"r1.json" ".results[$j]" > ${dateout}_${company}_${job}.json
done
```

Now when I replace r1 by r$i and add ((i=1;i<=52;j++)) it doesn't work... So I guess my problem comes from nested loop syntax in jq...

r1.json would look like that :

```
 {

    "radius" : 25,
    "totalResults" : 1329,

    "results" : [

                {
                    "jobtitle" : "job1",
                    "company" : "company1,
                    "date" : "Sun, 01 Sep 2015 07:59:58 GMT",
}
,
                {
                    "jobtitle" : "job2",
                    "company" : "company2",
                    "date" : "Sun, 02 Sep 2015 07:59:58 GMT",
}
,
            |...]
                {
                    "jobtitle" : "job25",
                    "company" : "company25,
                    "date" : "Sun, 25 Sep 2015 07:59:58 GMT",
}

    ]
}
```

Comment: You realize you could do all this logic in only one `jq` call (per output file)? It's a much more powerful scripting language than you're giving it credit for here.

Comment: Also, "doesn't work" -- **how** doesn't it work? Show the exact error message if you get one.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy now it works. I'd be curious to know more about jq scripting language though. Would you have some good references to share ?

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/ is the canonical source. Note that it allows you to join strings together with the `+` operator, so instead of retrieving all these values with separate invocations and then combining them in bash, you could combine them into one on the `jq` side.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use +. I started to read this doc in order to understand loops with jq, but I didn't get anything of their prose...

Comment: The tricky thing about using exclusively jq loops rather than bash loops for your use case is the need to split output into multiple files; right now, jq contains facilities to allow input files to be controlled from the script, but that's not the case for output.

Comment: ...now, that's not to say it couldn't all be brought down to just one jq instance generating an output stream that a bash instance reading it could loop over and split into multiple files -- but one would have to be clever about it. I have a few ideas, but I'd want to test them first.

Comment: see also [JSON array to bash variables using jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, and my issue didn't come from jq but from the syntax I was using for nested loops... Here it is :

```
for ((i=1;i<=kdr;i++))
do
   for ((j=0;j<=24;j++))
   do
    datein=$(jq <"r$i.json" ".results[$j].date" | sed 's/"//g')
    dateout=$(date -d "${datein}" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    company=$(jq <"r$i.json" ".results[$j].company" | sed 's/,//g;s/"//g;s/ //g')
    job=$(jq <"r$i.json" ".results[$j].jobtitle" | sed 's/,//g;s/"//g;s/ //g')
    jq <"r$i.json" ".results[$j]" > ${dateout}_${company}_${job}.json
   done
done
```

Comment: calling jq 1000 times is slow. see also [JSON array to bash variables using jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq)

Answer (score 0):

You should respect the bash syntax in your `for`s:

`for (( i=0; i<5; i++ ))`

`((i=1,i< =52,j++))` won't work, use `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: Sure, you're right, thanks, I edited my post. unfortunately my issue doesn't come from that mistake.

Comment: Try breaking up your script so that each line is less than 70 characters long. Avoid using backticks (e.g. use `$( EXPR )`).  Also try defining and using functions (e.g. bash functions).  By breaking up your problem, you will probably solve it.  If not, it will make it much easier for others to help.

Comment: @peak, thx for you advise. I broke up the scrpit and edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

1) You wrote that your i-loop used ((i=1;i< =52;j++)); that should be `((i-1; i<=52; i++))`

2) We can't see exactly what you did with respect to r1 and r$i, so if (1) doesn't resolve your difficulty, maybe you should double-check that what you did is actually what is needed.  Should you change "> $outputname" to ">> $outputname"?

3) I suspect that rather than using `s/"//g`, it might be better to use the -r option of jq; you might also consider avoiding sed altogether (jq 1.5 has sub and gsub functions).

4) As I said, it would be better to get rid of all the backticks.

Comment: 1) You're right, I amended it, thx

2) The issue is that I can't manage to have something like this : 

for i=1, do for j=0, j=2, ..., j=24

for i=2, do for j=0, j=2, ..., j=24
...

for i=52, do for j=0, j=2, ..., j=24

3) Thx for the tip, I'll get a look at jq documentation

4) I just edited the question and removed them